# How to check out if SX1276 module is working properly?

Tags: python, iot, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, lora

I want to find out if my LoRa module is working properly with Raspberry Pi Pico W.

I am using an SX1276 module, a Raspberry Pi Pico W and this is the connection scheme:

```
Raspberry Pi Pico --------------> LoRa SX1276
SCK (GP10) -------------------> SCK
MOSI (GP11) ------------------> MOSI
MISO (GP8) -------------------> MISO
GP1 ----------------------------> Reset
GND ----------------------------> GND
```

I asked ChatGPT the same question and it gave me some code ideas. The current code state is:

```py
import machine
import time
from machine import Pin
from machine import SPI

# SPI initialization
spi = SPI(1, sck=Pin(10), mosi=Pin(11), miso=Pin(8))

# Reset initialization
rst = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)

# LoRa module boot up
rst.value(0)
time.sleep(0.01)
rst.value(1)

# Waiting for LoRa initialization
time.sleep(0.5)

# The function responsible for sending data and receiving responses from the LoRa module
def send_recv(data, length):
    rx_buf = bytearray(length)
    print(rx_buf)
    spi.readinto(rx_buf, length)
    return rx_buf

# A function to send a command and receive a response
def get_version():
    tx_buf = bytearray([0x42, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])
    rx_buf = send_recv(tx_buf, 4)
    return rx_buf[3]

# Download the version of the LoRa module
version = get_version()
print('LoRa module version: ', version)

if version == 0x12:
    print('LoRa module working!')
else:
    print('LoRa module, not working properly')
```

I am also not sure about the correctness of this MicroPython code.

When I run this script, the output is:

```py
>>> %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00')
LoRa module version:  0
LoRa module, not working properly
```

I am expecting something more than an empty bytearray...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **REALLY** use a library instead of hacking your own... As it is now your code has a few issues, the main one being that you are using `spi.readinto` wrong.

```py
rxdata = bytearray(1)
try:
  cs(0) # Select peripheral.
  spi.readinto(rxdata, 0x42) # Read **1** byte in place while writing 0x42.
finally:
  cs(1) # Deselect peripheral.
```

The version register is **one** byte, `0x42`, and returns **one** byte, `0x12`. Not four each.

What is this `cs` you ask? Well yeah, you need a Chip Select pin, so that the LoRa module knows you are talking to it... With your current code you shouldn't be expecting anything but an empty `bytearray`, since you're not talking to any device.

No, but really, use a library...

Comment: Thank you for support, but unfortunately module still isn't working. I uploaded newest code into git repo:
https://github.com/Tomson601/pico_lora/blob/main/lora.py
I aware that I should use an library, but I just want to find out if my LoRa module is working properly.

Comment: Update: I managed to dump LoRa module's register using Arduino Uno and Lora Library.